# C program to accept a string input and print number of vowels and most repeated vowels in the string

Tags: c, string, frequency

I am learning C so I am doing different C programming challenges one of which is this program. *WAP to accept a string input from the user and print the no. vowels and the most repeated vowel in the string.*

I am able to calculate and print the number of vowels but I am not able to figure out how should I calculate the most repeated vowel in the string though I can print out directly on the output screen, the most repeated vowel just by having a print statement of `vowels[i]` inside the inner loop. But I want to calculate the most repeated vowel inside the program itself and then just print it efficiently. I tried different things but nothing worked. Also, I want to keep the code small and efficient. Is there a way to that?

This is what I did so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 150

int main()
{
    char Statement[MAX];
    char vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    int i, j;

    puts("Enter a simple statement.");
    fgets(Statement, 150, stdin);
    printf("\nYou entered: %s\n", Statement);
    for(i=0; i<=strlen(Statement); i++){
        //Converting uppercase input to lowercase
        Statement[i] = tolower((unsigned char)Statement[i]);
    }
    //Calling the function to print no. of 
    NumberOfVowels(Statement, vowels); vowels

    return 0;
}

    int NumberOfVowels(char Statement[], char vowels[])
    {
        int i, j, vowelsAmount = 0, count = 0;
        for(i=0; i<5; i++){                             //outer loop

                for(j=0; j<=strlen(Statement); j++){    //inner loop
                if(vowels[i] == Statement[j]){
                vowelsAmount++;
                printf("%c - ", vowels[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        printf("\nTotal number of vowels = %d", vowelsAmount);
        return vowelsAmount;
    }
```

Comment: suggestion: create an array of counters, one per a letter. There are just 256 of them max in c strings. initialize all of them to '0' and than increment a corresponding one `counter[vowel[i]] ++` or similar. at the end you can figure out max and min.

Comment: The simplest to understand would be to create a second array to hold the count of each vowel. An alternative would be making your `vowels` array 2D to keep the count of each vowel.

Comment: @Serge I tried including a counter inside the inner loop it worked fine for `vowels[0]` but I am not able to extract the value of the counter after every `vowel[i]` is finished with the inner loop. Because of this it prints the right value of occurrence for `vowels[0]` but then it keeps on adding after `i>0` .

Comment: @SrijanSingh you have to declare the array of counters outside of any loops but inside of your function. whatever you declare inside `{ ..}` is not visible outside of this scope. you need to find out a correct scope to declare your variables. So, `vowelCount` is visible in any scope of your function but not in a different function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try any of the below approach ...

- Create a struct `MAP` with `key` and `value` as members. Have helper methods that allow you to populate `MAP` struct with `key` as `vowel` and value as no. of `occurrences`.
- Create a 2D array of vowel where row represents the `vowels` and column no. of `occurrences`.
- Simplest to understand would be creating an array of size 256 (`ascii`) and keep on increment the value at `array[ascii(vowel)]` by 1 on each occurrence.

Here is one of the implementation (I have just updated your code so its crude, please work on making it look good and remove redundant prints)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 150

    int NumberOfVowels(char Statement[], char vowels[], int counts[])
    {
        int i, j = 0;

        for(j=0; j<strlen(Statement); j++) {
            if (Statement[j] == '\0' || Statement[j] == '\n') {
                continue;
            }
            for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
                if(vowels[i] == Statement[j]) {
                    int ascii = (int) vowels[i];
                    counts[ascii] = counts[ascii] + 1;
                }
            }
        }

        for(i=0; i<5; i++) {
            int ascii = (int) vowels[i];
            printf("%c - %d ", vowels[i], counts[ascii]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }

int main()
{
    char Statement[MAX];
    char vowels[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    int counts[256] = {0};
    int i, j;

    puts("Enter a simple statement.");
    fgets(Statement, 150, stdin);
    printf("\nYou entered: %s\n", Statement);
    for(i=0; i<=strlen(Statement); i++){
        //Converting uppercase input to lowercase
        Statement[i] = tolower((unsigned char)Statement[i]);
        printf("%c ", Statement[i]);
    }
    //Calling the function to print no. of 
    NumberOfVowels(Statement, vowels, counts);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample Run

```
You entered: Hello How are you, I am fine!                                                                                                                           

h e l l o   h o w   a r e   y o u ,   i   a m   f i n e !    

  a - 2 e - 3 i - 2 o - 3 u - 1
```

Comment: I tried including a counter inside the inner loop it worked fine for `vowels[0]` but I am not able to extract the value of the counter after every `vowel[i]` is finished with the inner loop. Because of this it prints the right value of occurrence for `vowels[0]` but then it keeps on adding after `i>0` .

Comment: If solution solves your problem then accept the answer and vote up!